# doesn't publish data strings that i subscribed

Tags: python, mqtt

In the following script i can subscribe from a topic but it wont publish my data strings and i don't get an error message. Are some functions out of order?

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

broker = "broker"                   #Broker address
port = 1883                         #Broker port
user = "user"                       #Connection username
psw = "psw"                         #Connection password
client = mqtt.Client("Python")
client.username_pw_set(user, psw)
client.connect(broker, port, 60)

pubtopic = 'pubtopic'
def on_publish(client, pubtopic, msg):
    print("publish data")
    client.publish(pubtopic, msg.payload)
    on_publish(client, msg.payload)


subtopic = 'subtopic'
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("received: " + str(rc))
    client.subscribe(subtopic)


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))


client.on_publish = on_publish
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: The only call to `publish` I can see is in [`on_publish`](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#on-publish) which will only get called when a message has been transmitted. As you are not publishing anything this will never get called (and if it did you would end up with an infinite loop). Please explain what you want to publish and how this should be triggered.

Comment: I constantly receive messages from 150 topics. And when in one of these topics a new message arrives, i want to publish it instantly in another topic.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `on_publish` callback it's not doing anything useful here, as @Brits mentioned, it is only called when this particular client publishes a message (which you are not doing in your current code) and the 3rd argument is not a full message object, it is just a message id field.

Please send some time and read the Python Paho [doc](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#callbacks) section on callbacks.
It clearly lays out under what conditions each callback will be triggered.

If you want to react to a message you have subscribed to then you need an `on_message` callback. It is within this function that you need do any actions as a result of receiving that message.

e.g.

```py
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
    client.publish(pubtopic, msg.payload)
```